# What scripture talks about Karṇa's third curse by Bhūdevī or Goddess of Earth?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, karna, bhumi

In my [recent answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16919/2995), I argued that both of Karṇa's two unfortunate curses were interpolations i.e., they were not part of Vyāsa's original Mahābhārata. I think the reason behind those particular interpolations is to elevate the stature of Karṇa, i.e., show him on par with Arjuna and that he'd be unbeatable if not for those two curses - one from a brāhmaṇa and other from Paraśurāma.

Apparently, there's a third curse-story mentioned in various online blogs according to which Karṇa tried to squeeze out spilled ghee (clarified butter) from soil which upset Bhūdevī (Goddess of Earth), so she cursed Karṇa.

The full story from [one such blog](http://varunmnayak.blogspot.com/2010/02/karna-and-three-curses.html) is:

> Sometime later, when he was on a tour of his new kingdom, Karna is said to have encountered a girl who was crying out of fear of her step mother since her ghee had fallen to the ground. Being generous enough Karna told her that he would give her new ghee. But, the child insisted that she wanted only the ghee that was mixed with the soil and refused to take the new ghee. Taking pity on the girl, Karna took the soil mixed with ghee in his fist and squeezed it with all his might to extract the ghee and pour it back into the pot. However, Bhoomi Devi (Mother Earth) was furious at him for hurting her for the sake of a mere child. **So, the Earth goddess cursed him that in a very crucial battle of his life, she would trap his chariot wheel in the same way that he held the fistful of soil, thereby making him vulnerable to his enemy.**
>
> Thus, Karna was cursed on three separate and independent occasions.

What is the origin of the above story? Which scripture contains it? Can you cite the exact verses or their translation from the relevant scripture?

Comment: IMHO, the story of Bhudevi's curse is extremely absurd, because 1. We cannot squeeze pure and clean ghee out of mud 2. Bhudevi being Compassion and Forgiveness (Kshama) personified, wouldn't waste her time cursing someone for squeezing **mud** (which is not even part of her body given that he lifted the mud).

Comment: 3. If she gets angry for mere squeezing of mud, humans should have been extinct for all the activities they perform on earth - simple example is farming, building a house, what to talk about other activities like mining and excavation.

Comment: @Surya Totally agree. I think the story is sourced from a local version of the Mahābhārata e.g., [Andhra MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Mahabharatam).

Comment: While I think that the story is not from any version of Mahabharata - except the oral rendition by someone which has passed from ear to mouth.

Comment: @Surya I found an Eng. tr. of AMB [here](http://www.telugubhakti.com/telugupages/Monthly/Mahabharat/content802.htm). In the conversation b/w Karna and Shalya, the topic of curses comes up. Here's what Karna says: "O Salya! I am only afraid of the curse of my Guru and this Brahmin but not for the vigour and valour of Arjuna and Krishna. The Brahma Astra is well in my memory. Drive our chariot towards Arjuna. I will kill him with my Brahma Astra." – No mention of Bhudevi curse.

Comment: @sv. Andhra MB is not a baseless book like other folklores in other regional languages. It is translated based on vyasa MB only. But the trio of poets added poetic imagery to make it more enjoyable. I think this curse is not from Andhra MB.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, I agree AMB is true to Vyasa MB. See my comment [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16940/did-draupad%c4%ab-ridicule-duryodhana-calling-him-blind-son-of-a-blind-father#comment43582_16941).

Comment: To be completely honest, if someone is cursed on three separate occasions, by three separate people, one which is known for impartiality, it shows him to be solely at fault, not luck.