# If Ayodhya Ram temple is so dear to Hindus, why don't we see lord Krishna ever visiting ayodhya/talk about his last avtar ? (500 years dream of hindus

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, buddhism, ayodhya

Heard that avatars concept is fabricated at the time of Buddhism.

Comment: Actually, Lord Buddha talks about his last avatar as Rama at [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasaratha_Jataka#:~:text=The%20Jataka%20describes,Sita%20followed%20him.), it is the only instance of a god talking about his last avatar that I've found till now. Although a bit of disparity exists.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate [Did Krishna ever talk about Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36816/did-krishna-ever-talk-about-rama)

Comment: Also, you seem like an Abrahamic or atheist hater. Kṛṣṇa existed more than 2000 yrs before, and he is already dead. Rāma existed more than 4 mahāyugas ago, and he is dead too.
Avatāras are mentioned in itihāsa-purāṇa, which are far older than Śākyamuni Buddha. Furthermore, Bauddhas don't accept daśāvatāra, nor do they accept an Īśvara fyi. Don't bring up your resentment for Rāma mandira here. This is not reddit, quora, etc., it's a serious platform.

Comment: @Bingming Rama Mandira?

Comment: Pali canon was not entirely authored by buddha. It was composed by his later followers that too in sri lanka. This is mentioned in pali canon itself. Pali canon has lot of errors while describing vedas, ramayana, etc. Lot of content of pali canon is a copy paste of shanti/anusasana parva with modifications.

Comment: @ekAntika I agree, but this was the closest I could bring to show avatarvaad. I don't know any other sources out of Vedas and Upanishads. Additionally, Pali Canon is accepted in canonical terms only, so most of the Buddhists reject them and don't believe it to be an avatar.

Answer (score 0):

[Shatapatha Brahmana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatapatha_Brahmana) has details of matasya, kurma, vaman avtars of shri hari.

Shatpath Brahmana which has been [Dated](https://www.swaminarayan.org/essays/2009/0801.htm) 3500 BC (date is centuries prior to even birth of buddha)

An example

> Vaman avtar
>
> The gods then heard of this, and said: 'The Asuras are actually
> dividing this earth: come, let us go to where the Asuras are dividing
> it. For what would become of us, if we were to get no share in it?'
> Placing Vishnu, (in the shape of) this very sacrifice, at their head,
> they went (to the Asuras). They then said: 'Let us share in this earth
> along with yourselves! Let a part of it be ours!' The Asuras replied
> rather grudgingly: 'As much as this Vishnu lies upon, and no more, we
> give you!' Now Viṣṇu was a dwarf. The gods, however, were not offended
> at this, but said: 'Much indeed they gave us, who gave us what is
> equal in size to the sacrifice.' Shatapatha Brahmana, translated by
> Julius Eggeling (1900), Kanda I, Adhyaya 2, Brahmana 5, Verses 1–7

[Other question is already answered](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36816/did-krishna-ever-talk-about-rama)

Comment: It doesn't mention anywhere as *avatar* explicitly. It just mentions of few details of matasya, kurma, vaman, etc. Please quote otherwise.

Comment: This is your quote: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63121.html Not even a single place the word, *Vaman* has been written anywhere. Neither the verse 10, *10. This, however, one must not do. Among the roots of the plants he (Viṣṇu) hid himself: therefore let him (the Adhvaryu) bid (the Āgnīdhra) to cut out the roots of the plants. And since they found (anu-vid) Viṣṇu in that place, therefore it is called vedi (altar).* confines anywhere with the story of Vamana. This answer is only based on resemblance. It doesn't shows *avatarvaad*

Comment: @User29449 exact avtar word is not even in gita  . I can't understand what you are saying

Comment: The OP is asking a question related to Avatarvaad. If there are any sources where god themselves affirmed about avatarvaad. Your answer is a section of vedas describing a story that closely resembles Vamana.