# How did Karna die in his previous birth?

Tags: mahabharata, karna

In his previous birth Karna received a boon that he can survive death a 1000 times.

And to kill him once one has to pray to god for 1000 years.

Then how did he die?

Comment: See answers [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2367/2995) and [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6909/2995).

Comment: I wanted to know how did he died in his previous birth. Both the post you highlighted says about his past life but did not tell how he died.

Comment: If you look at the linked answers, you make out that he did not die or died of natural causes. If you want you can edit one of those questions (e.g., [this one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6909/2995)) and add your question about how did he die in his previous birth. A totally separate question on just how did he die in his previous birth seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

he was dambhodbhav demon in last birth...as u know nar & narayan who were arjun & krishna of next birth defeated him...dambhodbhav got boon of 1000 sheilds & whoever break sheild will die...nar used to fight 1000 yrs & narayan used to meditate then when nar break the sheild & die the narayan by mediation's punya used to bring nar back to life & then nar meditate & narayan fight & so on they broke 999 sheilds but then with 1 sheild left the demon ran to abode of sun & then took birth of karna...& it is also said that after karna birth karna took a birth of devotee of lord shiva who was siru thonda nayanar...as per south indian beliefs...:)

Comment: Please cite sources.

Comment: about siru thonda nayanar source was quora & this story is available everywhere!:)

Comment: Quora is not an acceptable source here.  See [this question](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/53/3500).

Comment: ok..i will find a better support to my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Karna was not anything like Dambhodbhav or anything else. He was son of Brahma.

> 3-4. Formerly when his face was rent, Brahma, overpowered by great anger, took up the perspiration produced on his forehead and struck it on the ground; **from that perspiration a brave hero having rings, arrows and a great bow and having a thousand armours was born** and he said: “What shall I do?”
>
> 47. Going to their battlefield and warding them off he said to both of them: “In the intervening period between the Kali and Dvāpara yugas,
>       in your next birth there will be (a war); when the great war will take
>       place I shall bring both of you together (to fight).”
> 48. Viṣṇu having called the lord of planets and the lord of gods told them: “By my command these two good men are to be protected by you.
> 49. O sun (having a thousand rays), this one born of the perspiration (of Brahmā) is to be descended on the earth as your portion at the end
>       of the Dvāpara (yuga) for the success of gods.
> 50. In the family of the Yadus there will be born very mighty Śūra.
> 51. His glorious daughter Pṛthā, incomparable in beauty on the earth will be born for the success of gods; and Durvāsas will grant her a
>       boon and a group of spells:
> 52. ‘Whatever god she (i.e. you) would invoke with that spell by the favour of that god, O venerable lady, you will obtain a son’.
> 53. O Sun, she during her menses seeing you rising will long for you; when she is (thus) afflicted with anxiety you should enjoy her.
> 54. In her i.e. **Kuntī’s womb he will be (conceived and) born as the son ofan unmarried woman** for the success of gods, O lord.”
> 55. The Sun, the heap of lustre Saying “All right” spoke (further): “On the maiden I shall generate a son who will be proud ofhis power.
> 56. And all people will address him by the name **Karṇa**. O Viṣṇu, due to my favour in the world there will be nothing with him, of a
>       pure soul, that will not be given to brāhmaṇas, O Keśava.

You could read this complete scenario in [Padma Purana.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364134.html)