# What is the story of Kedarnath Jyotirlinga?

Tags: shiva, scripture, temple, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

Lord Shiva has been worshipped in Linga form from time beginning as described in [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/101/why-is-shiva-primarily-worshipped-in-a-linga-form/14214#14214) Among the Lingas there are 12 Jyotirlingas which are of special importance.

Mahatmya of 12 Jyotirlingas is described in Koti Rudra Samhita of Shiva Purana in the chapter "Dwadash Jyotirlinga Mahatmya". It states:

> सौराष्ट्रे सोमनाथं च श्री शैले मल्लिकार्जुनम् ।
> उज्जयिन्यां महाकालमोंकारे परमेश्वरम् ।।
> **केदारं** हिमवत्पृष्ठे डाकिन्यां भीमशङ्करम् ।
> वाराणास्यां च विश्वेशं त्रयम्बकं गौतमीतटे ।।
> वैद्यनाथं चिताभूमौ नागेशं दारुकावने ।
> सेतुबन्धे तु रामेशं घुश्मेशं च शिवालये ।।
> **द्वादशैतानि नामानि प्रात्यस्त्थाय यः पठेत् ।
>
> सर्वपापविनिर्मुक्तं सर्वसिद्धिफलं लभेत्** ।।
>  
> Somanath in Saurashtra, Mallikarjuna in Shri Saile, Mahakala in Ujjaiyana and Parameshawara also manifested as Omkara. Kedara in Himavat and Bhima Shankara in Dakinya. Vishewaswara in Varanasi and Trayambaka in side of Gautami. Vaidyanath in ChitaBhumi and  Nageshwara in forest of Daruka. Rameshwara in Setubandha and Ghusmeshwara in Shivalaya. **These name of 12 Jyotirlingas who recites in morning, he gets freed from all sins and is eligible to get all Siddhis.**

There are twelve [Jyotirlingas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotirlinga#Sanskrit_Sloka) mentioned in the similar popular verse.

> Saurāṣṭre Somanāthaṃ ca Śrīśaile Mallikārjunam
>
> Ujjayinyāṃ Mahākālam Omkāram Mamleśhwaram
>
> Paraly Vaidyanāthaṃ cha Ḍākinyāṃ Bhīmaśhaṅkaram
>
> Setubandhe tu Rāmeśaṃ Nāgeśhaṃ Dārukāvane
>
> Vārāṇasyāṃ tu Viśveśaṃ Tryambakaṃ Gautamītaṭe
>
> Himālaye tu **Kedāraṃ** Ghuśmeśaṃ ca Śivālaye
>
> etāni jyotirliṅgāni sāyaṃ prātaḥ paṭhennaraḥ
>
> saptajanmakṛtaṃ pāpaṃ smaraṇena vinaśyati

I have already asked a question about Somanath [What is the story of Somanath Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/what-is-the-story-of-somanath-jyotirlinga) and Mallikarjun [What is the story of Mallikarjuna Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14223/what-is-the-story-of-mallikarjuna-jyotirlinga) and Mahakaleshwar [What is the story of Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14243/what-is-the-story-of-mahakaleshwar-jyotirlinga) and Omkareshwar [What is the story of Omkareshwar Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14264/what-is-the-story-of-omkareshwar-jyotirlinga) and Vaidyanath [What is the story of Vaidyanath Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/what-is-the-story-of-vaidyanath-jyotirlinga) and Bheemshankar [What is the story of Bheemshankar Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/what-is-the-story-of-bheemshankar-jyotirlinga) and Rameshwaram [What is the story of Rameshwaram Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14349/what-is-the-story-of-rameshwaram-jyotirlinga) and Nageshwar [What is the story of Nageshwar Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14359/what-is-the-story-of-nageshwar-jyotirlinga) and Vishwanatha [What is the story of Kasi Vishwanatha Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14367/what-is-the-story-of-kasi-vishwanatha-jyotirlinga) and Trayambakeshwara [What is the story of Trayambakeshwara Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/what-is-the-story-of-trayambakeshwara-jyotirlinga). Now I want to know the story of Kedarnath Jyotirling.

Please mention the scriptural reference.

Kedarnath temple is situated in [Uttarakhand](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B044%2706.7%22N+79%C2%B004%2700.9%22E/@30.735194,79.066917,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d30.735194!4d79.066917?hl=en).

[image]

By Shaq774 at en.wikipedia - Transferred from en.wikipedia Source at wikipedia, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=4624438

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nara-Narayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3712/3500) were two prominent sages, who were sons of Yama and previous births of Arjuna and Krishna respectively. They lived in [Badrikashrama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badrinath) and they were known for their fight with [Sahasrakavacha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6941/3500).

These sages did Tapasya for Lord Shiva daily and Shiva used to come here as *Parthiva Linga* pleased by their blessings. He stayed there as Kedarnatha Jyotirlinga.

The story of Kedarnatha Jyotirlinga is described in [Chapter 19](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-140/topic-1) Kotirudra Samhita of Shiva Purana.

> सूत उवाच
>  नरनारायणाख्यौ याववतारौ हरेर्द्विजाः।
>  तेषाते भारते
> खण्डे बदर्याश्रम एव हि॥ १॥
>  ताभ्यां सम्प्रार्थितः शम्भुः पार्थिवे
> पूजनाय वै।
>  आयाति नित्यं तल्लिङ्गे भक्ताधीनतया शिवः।। २ ।।
>
> Sūta said, “Nara-Nārāyaņa, the two incarnations of Visnu, are
> performing penance at Badrikāśrama Khanda in Bhārata-varsa. Śiva, in
> order to accept their worship of the Pärthiva-linga arrives there
> daily. This is because Siva is always subservient to his devotees
> arrives there daily. This is because Siva is always subservient to his
> devotees.
>
> एवं पूजयतोः शम्भुं तयोर्विष्ण्ववतारयोः। 
>  चिरकालो व्यतीयाय
> शैवयोर्धर्मपुत्रयोः।। ३॥
>  Those two incarnations of Visnu, and
> spiritual sons of Śiva, adored Siva there for a long time.
>
> एकस्मिन्समये तत्र प्रसन्नः परमेश्वरः।।
>  प्रत्युवाच प्रसन्नोऽस्मि
> वरो मे व्रियतामिति।।४॥
>
> Once the delightful Siva told them, “I am pleased with you. You better
> ask for your desired boon.”
>
> इत्युक्ते च तदा तेन नरो नारायणः स्वयम्। 
> ऊचतुर्वचनं तत्र लोकानां
> हितकाम्यया॥५॥
>
> At these words of Šiva, Nara-Nārāyana, spoke to Śiva, keeping in view
> the welfare of the world.
>
> नरनारायणावूचतुः
>  यदि प्रसन्नेो देवेश ! यदि देयो वरस्त्वया।
> स्थीयतां स्वेन रूपेण पूजार्थं शङ्कर! स्वयम्।। ६ ।।
>
> Nara-Nārāyana said, “O Lord of gods, in case you are pleased with us
> and intend to bestow a boon, then you stay here forever for our
> adoration.
>
> सूत उवाच
>  इत्युक्तस्तु तदा ताभ्यां केदारे हिमसंश्रये।
>  स्वयं च
> शङ्करस्तस्थौ ज्योतीरूपो महेश्वरः।।७।।
>
> Sūta said, “When both of them thus spoke, Šiva got himself established
> over the snow clad Kedara mountain, in Jyotirlinga.
>
> ताभ्यां च पूजितश्चैव सर्वदुःखभयापहः।
>  लोकानामुपकारार्थं भक्तानां
> दर्शनाय वै॥८॥
>
> The linga, having been adored by both of them (Nara-Nārāyaņa) the
> linga, which removed all types of dangers and pains, for the benefit
> of the people and for the devotees to have a look at it, was lodged,
> there, which could be seen even today.
>
> स्वयं स्थितस्तदा शम्भुः केदारेश्वरसंज्ञकः।
>  भक्ताभीष्टप्रदो नित्यं
> दर्शनादर्चनादपि।।९।।
>  Śiva is found present there in the form of
> Kedaresvara. The lord fulfills the desires of all who have an audience
> with the linga or worship it.