Is the story of Dambodbhava just folklore or is it supported by scripture?
The story goes Dambodbhava had a thousand armored shields and Nara and Narayana fought with him alternately to destroy his shields one by one, and Karna is said to be his final incarnation.

Are you talking about this answer? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/which-previous-karma-made-karnas-life-full-of-sorrow-despite-his-benevolent-nat/6942#6942

I am not able to see a clear connection between dambodbhava and Karna @CracklingCyclone
